# What linguistic structures appear in conditional statements?

Tags: conditionals

I am working on natural language processing and seek to determine if a given sentence is a conditional statement - ex:

- If I go to the store, then I will spend money.
- I would have gone to the store, if I was hungry.

What parts of speech appear in conditionals? What structures do they form in grammar, and how can I distinguish them from normal phrases?

Comment: I thought about it, but I'm not sure I'm really asking the same thing. Since my other question is so unclear I'll probably just close it.

Comment: Conditional statements have two parts, *antecedents* and *consequents*. The antecedent is usually introduced with **if**. For example: "**If** it rains, (then) I bring an umbrella". But other words can also be used in antecedents, for example: "**Were** it to rain, (then) I would bring an umbrella"; "**Had** she called, (then) I would have picked up"; and "**Could** he run, (then) he would have escaped". **Unless** might also indicate conditionals (see http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as)

Comment: What, if anything, delimits the two halves of the conditional?

Comment: The antecedent contains a word like **if**, **were**, **had**, **could**, **unless**, **should**, **as long as**, **provided that**, and so on. These words are good indicators, but just because they are present in a sentence, doesn't necessarily mean the sentence is a conditional. The consequent is often (but not always) introduced with **then**. Note that the consequent *can* appear *before* the antecedent (for example "He brings an umbrella **if** it rains").

Comment: For what it's worth, my intuition is that the **If [*clause*], (then) [*clause*]** structure along with the **[*clause*] if [*clause*]** structure are overwhelmingly the most common. Anything with these structures is a conditional.

Comment: @Silenus How about "[He didn't tell me] if [he's coming]"?

Comment: @Araucaria, good point! That's definitely not a conditional and yet fits one of the structures I gave. I was just trying to give OP some relatively simple rules to get him or her started. They will need to be refined. And refined again. AI language processing is TOUGH!

Comment: By the way, you might be able to block examples like @Araucaria 's from slipping though by abandoning the conditional analysis on the occasion that the **[*clause*] if [*clause*]** structure has a verb in the "apparent" antecedent which takes a clausal complement (for example 'tell', 'said', 'know', etc.). But such rules get more and more ad hoc with every counterexample! Good Luck!

Comment: Can you tell us which type of conditionals you're looking at?

Comment: Here's a couple of examples. The next step is to look at #1 and #2 and distinguish from #3.
`If successful, all three doors will open for approximately three seconds.`

`The system will shut down if the reset password is entered.`

`If you submit this information without permission, you will be subject to the ramifications of the Arms Export Control Act`

Of course, this gets more difficult when you include the sentences you want to distinguish from:
`For administrative actions, the lights on the door will blink two times for failure and stay lit for 15 seconds for success`

Comment: @Ares So not conditional's with *whether* or subject-auxiliary inversion or  *wh*-ever conditionals?

Comment: I suppose those are meaningful to process as well. Mostly I'm looking for statements that can tell me something about the input I'm processing. Thing processing the owner's manual of a car and looking for statements about the design and how it works - ex `Whenever the ignition is in the ACC position, the radio and windows work.` 

I'm currently looking for antecedents and modal verbs, but any extraction measures would help.

Comment: Sentences beginning with *if* are nearly always conditionals. Sentences with clauses beginning with *if* occurring after a comma are nearly always conditionals. The word *unless* is restricted nearly entirely to conditionals.